# wx.Frame does Hide if using self.Hide(), but does not Hide if self is not available

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, hide, sikuli

I have two apps (wx.App), say GUI A and GUI B, which can talk via twisted. B has a collection of Sikuli scripts, and A should be able to send a message to execute a selected Sikuli script in B.
Among other things, B has:
(1) a combobox to select a specific sikuli
(2) a button to run that selected sikuli
(3) a twisted protocol (lineReceiver) to talk with A. I can access the protocol with self.protocol. On the other hand, the protocol has access to the GUI using its factory (this is twisted specific, but it is gui=self.factory.gui). With this, I can set/get GUI attributes and call GUI methods.

Because Sikuli needs to work with the display, I need that when I want to run a Sikuli, the app needs to be Hiden, execute Sikuli, and then the app needs to be Shown. **That is working OK** if I only work with B, and for that the methods are:

```
def functionHide(self,event):
    self.Hide()
    wx.CallAfter(self.OnRunSikulis)

def OnRunSikulis(self):
    try:
        runSikuli(the selected sikuli) #this is not literal, but here is not the problem
    except:
        print "There is a problem.."
        wx.CallAfter(self.functionShow)
    else:
        wx.CallAfter(self.functionShow)

def functionShow(self):
    self.SetFocus()
    self.Show(True)
```

OK, now I want to send a message from A to B, in order to run a Sikuli. When the message arrives to B, it is processed by its protocol function lineReceived. Here it is a reduced version of lineReceived:

```
def lineReceived(self, line):
    gui = self.factory.gui
    linea= line.split("*")
    parameter=linea[0]

    if parameter == "ERR_NAME":
        self.factory.continueTrying = False
        return
    elif parameter == "EXE_SIKULI":
        wx.CallAfter(gui.functionHide,wx.EVT_BUTTON) #of course, for functionHide I use Bind with the execute sikuli button

        return
    return
```

OK, besides many things, I want to say:

- Here self means the protocol, not the GUI B
- When parameter == "EXE_SIKULI", you can see "gui.functionHide" (I can not use self.functionHide here)
- The sikuli is run OK, without any problem, as if it were executed by pressing the button in the GUI
- **THE PROBLEM: it does not Hide the GUI B**

I read a lot and tested some other things besides CallAfter (wx.PostEvent, wx.PyCommandEvent).

Any help about hiding the GUI B would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the `lineReceived` function is not a part of the GUI B class?  Does whatever has this function have access to GUI B?

Comment: Can you create a small runnable example that we can take a look at?

Comment: lineReceived is a method of my protocol. The GUI B class has an instance of my protocol (inside GUI B class, I can do self.protocol.anyMethod). Protocols are created by a factory class from inside the GUI B class, and the GUI instance is an attribute when start using the factory. In this way, the factory can be aware of the GUI. And you can have access to the GUI B inside the protocol with "self.factory.gui"  @MikeDriscoll

Comment: So where is the `self.factory.gui.Hide()` command?

Comment: functionHide is in the GUI B class. It works if you "invoke" it from the GUI, but it does not work when you use (from the protocol) self.factory.gui.functionHide(). I am suspecting it is a matter of timing, because sometimes it is hiden @MikeDriscoll

Comment: I would recommend using pubsub then. It can send a message to the GUI to Hide itself. My guess is that the event that CallAfter puts on the stack doesn't always get executed immediately.

Comment: I tried with pub sub, it gave me the same problems. But now I have new clues: the problem seems to be in linux (or in the linux machine) with the function Hide. Until now I was trying to execute GUI A and GUI B in the same linux machine. So I was testing using GUI B in Windows and GUI A in linux. In that case, both with wx.CallAfter and pubsub, it worked OK (the frame hides, the sikuli is executed, and the frame shows), but not if vice versa. Any comment? Also, windows machine is slower, maybe because of that it has time to hide the GUI.. @MikeDriscoll

Comment: Also, I have used the function IsShownOnScreen() to look for a GUI element (such a button). When executed before functionHide(), it prints TRUE, and after that it prints FALSE. Then I have to think it "believes" it is hiden when it is not. @MikeDriscoll